# What is the story behind this hadith?

Tags: hadith-interpretation

why did prophet Muhammad almost divorce all of his wives, are they authentic? I seen two separate versions one with honey and another was an incident with Maria and Hafsa

this is the hadith:
https://sunnah.com/bukhari:2468

Comment: Isn't this covered in [Explanation of at_Tahrim veres 66:1](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/31259/explanation-of-at-tahrim-verse-1-661)

Comment: @Medi1Saif I believe it is. But the one you pointed out is referring to (an ayah) while ambrin is asking about (the hadith). Perhaps he wanted to get a different perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assalamualaikum, May Allah loves you even more. The hadith ([Bukhari:2468](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:2468)) was related to a story mentioned in Quran ([AT-TAHRIM:1 to 5](https://quran.com/66)). You may read more about the theme of the surah here: https://quran.com/chapter_info/66

The answer to your first question: `What is the story behind the hadith?` was answered in the 3rd sentence (AT-TAHRIM:3). Where Hafsah finds out that our beloved prophet Muhammad (upon whom be peace) were told by Allah, that she had broken a secret between her and the prophet when she told Aisya about it.

I believe that it is a (marriage/relationship/household) secret that should be kept between the couple. As the prophet would not keep anything secret if it was part of his duty as a prophet.

Hafsah shouldn't tell their household secret to anyone, as it would bring jealousy and conflict amongst them (prophet's wives).

In this case, Allah came to interfere and corrected Hafsah on the mater.

I would also like to note that we should not dig deeper into their personal maters because it would not give us any additional benefit. Allah mention the story for us to learn some lessons about keeping good marital relationship.

Allah knows best.

Comment: I can't say more about the (ifs). I did not know about their personal maters. if its not what we thought is (true/correct). then we would commit a great sin (fitna) to our beloved prophet. I leave their personal matters to them.

Comment: There is a discussion upon this here: https://www.abuaminaelias.com/hafsa-maria-surat-at-tahreem/ and i would like to note that: This narration comes on the authority of Zaid ibn Aslam who was from the third generation and not a witness to the events in question. Hence, Ibn Hajar rules that this narrations’s chain of authorities is incomplete (mursal) in Fatḥ al-Bārī 9/288. For this reason, the explanation was not universally agreed upon by the classical commentators. Aisha was the direct witness about whom the verses speak, so she would know best what really happened.

Comment: I personally thinks that the story about honey can be directly related to TAHRIM:3 rather than the other version of the story (after third generation) where Hafsa protest over her husband's and Maria.